# Using cast on a view in a Derby database that has multiple columns

Tags: sql, derby

This question is a quick one. I know that you could say something like `SELECT CAST(someColumn AS otherType) FROM myView`, where myView is a view in a Derby database, but is it combinable with other statements in a `SELECT` statement? In other words, could I say something like `SELECT columnA, CAST(columnB AS otherType), someOtherColumns FROM myView`, or would you have to cast YOUR ENTIRE QUERY? //I have been looking online for something that might help, but with no examples of this. I have even tried this on w3schools.com, but it was complaining that the database is read-only (somehow, `cast()` was changing the database!). Otherwise, I have found no working examples where someone has done something like what I am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to that question: yes, you can say something like I have said above in Derby. Here is an example: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ad-trifecta6/ //although I still couldn't use those methods on a database on w3schools.com!

You do not have to cast the entire freaking table; you could just cast one column at a time! Heck, in Derby, you could say `DOUBLE(23)`, and it would return something like `23.000000`!

Comment: Correct: CAST is something you do to a value, not to an entire row or table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what either `Derby` or `w3schools.com` means, but you need to understand that **CAST** is a function and all functions have syntax that is particular to whatever environment you are in.  Many functions follow ANSI standard syntax but many others do not, especially in database languages.  It doesn't make sense to use a function "on an entire query".

[***Here is a link***](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/index.html) to the Derby version 10.10 documentation for your **DOUBLE** function, a function that creates a floating point value (which is why you see it displayed as "23.000000").  When you get to that page, scroll down to the functions described in the section labeled "Built-in functions".  You'll also see the documentation for the **CAST** function as well.

And note that although I've never heard of Derby before today, having access to the documentation like this means I'd fell comfortable developing code for it if the need ever came up.

In other words, always consult the documentation for the correct version of the database you are using!

Comment: Thank you so much for posting that. That `DOUBLE()` function was just what this programmer ordered! hahaha